# Difference between SimpleXMLElement PHP for and foreach loops?

Tags: php, xml, for-loop, foreach, iterator

I would like to know whether in PHP 5.6.11 there is any difference between the following two ways of iterating with SimpleXMLElement:

```
$simpleXMLIterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($xmlCode);

foreach ($simpleXMLIterator as $xmlElement) {

  echo $xmlElement->getName(), "\n";

}
```

and

```
$simpleXMLIterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($xmlCode);

for ($simpleXMLIterator->rewind(); $simpleXMLIterator->valid(); $simpleXMLIterator->next()) {

 echo $simpleXMLIterator->current()->getName(), "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will call the same logic inside the object. `Iterator` is an interface that you can implement into your own objects. The interface specifies methods like `rewind()`, `next()`, `current()`, ...

If you implement the interface the object can be used with `foreach()`. `foreach()` recognizes the interface and calls the methods.

`SimpleXMLIterator` implements that interface, more specific it implements `RecursiveIterator` which extends `Iterator` with two methods (`hasChildren()` and `getChildren()` to handle recursive structures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer: you have explained the foreach bit. But could you please also explain why the for loop cannot be brought to behave the same as the foreach loop? Why aren't the two the same thing? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? "It will call the same logic inside the object."

Comment: Perhaps the difference is that with the foreach loop you only have access to the elements encapsulated by the Traversable object being traversed, whereas with a for loop you will have access to the Traversable object itself inside the loop as well. The latter may be advantageous if the code needs to call methods on the enclosing traversed object as well. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, you can use the iterator methods inside the foreach().

Comment: How so? In the above code `$xmlElement` is a reference to `$simpleXMLIterator->current()`, so the reference to the `$simpleXMLIterator` itself should be gone? I think this concept would remain pretty much the same no matter what iterator and iterator elements you are using. So then you use foreach only when you need to access the elements without needing to access the iterator itself (for instance you may not need to call its `hasChildren()` or `getChildren()` methods in the case of `SimpleXMLIterator`.

Comment: `$simpleXMLIterator` is available inside the `foreach()`. Why would you think it is not?

Comment: OK, that clarifies the problem I was having. I was not aware about the fact that the left-hand-side element in a foreach loop is also accessible. Thank you for answering my question.